# Searching for a string that is generated dynamically, in a column of another SQL Server table

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
create table #data_search (
    tab1 varchar(50)
)

insert into #data_search values('chan')

create table #data (
     tab1 varchar(50)
)

insert into #data values('afachandra')
insert into #data values('achandra')
insert into #data values('afadra')

Declare @query varchar(50);
Declare @quer varchar(50);

select @query = tab1 
from #data_search;

-- print(@query)

SET @quer = 'select tab1 from #data where tab1 like %'+@query+'%'
execute (@quer);
```

I have above tables, where I am searching 'tab1' column of '#data_search' table in 'tab1' column of '#data' table. I have tried using dynamic SQL statements, but it's not working. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: are you saying you have two sql servers? if yes use linked server

Comment: your question isn't clear

Comment: I have two tables in same server. I want search a string of one table, in another table.

Comment: @maSTArHiAn I have two tables in same database. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should work

using LIKE and Exists

```
select * from #data d
where exists (
select 1 from #data_search s where d.tab1 like '%' + s.tab1 + '%'
)
```

Result

```
tab1
--------------------------------------------------
afachandra
achandra
```

Comment: Thanks @mastarhian